# Is it OK to delete a .nupkg file?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I'm new to NuGet -- just started using it and got myself a copy of WatiN.

I'm trying to trim down the size of the folder that was pulled back before I put it into version control.  I noticed that WatiN.2.0.50.nupkg is about 12mb.  I noticed from [this link](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/172) that the .nupkg is essentially a compressed version of the package contents.  Is it OK to delete it, or might doing so cause any issues in the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you delete it we can't update/uninstall since we use that file as a record of what is currently installed. We're looking at a feature that would allow people to restore the packages from packages.config so you *could* avoid putting packages in source control altogether. More info here http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/165