# What is the proper tfignore for NuGet packages folder in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, nuget, nuget-package, ignore

I have a shared NuGet `packages` folder inside my TFS repository and I want TFS to ignore extra files inside this folder.

This is currently the contents of my `tfignore` file, but I think we are over-ignoring things:

```
# NuGet autogenerate files

*.nupkg
*.nuget.props
*.nuget.targets
project.lock.json
project.assets.json

# Unwanted files (everything except for DLL)

*.js
*.ps1
*.p7s
*.transform
*.css
*.eot
*.svg
*.ttf
*.woff
*.map
*.xml
*.xdt
*.pp
*.props
*.rsp
*.targets
*.config
*.ini
*.txt
*.rtf
```

For example it seems `nukpg` should exist on all machines according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5255393/366064)

What is the minimal and correct `tfignore` content for this purpose?

Comment: Just ignore the packages folder entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `nukpg` is the packages, you for sure you need to ignore them and not check in them into TFS (during the build you run `nuget restore`).

Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/packages-and-source-control) recomand this `.tfignore` for NuGet:

```
 # Ignore NuGet Packages
*.nupkg

# Ignore the NuGet packages folder in the root of the repository. If needed, prefix 'packages'
# with additional folder names if it's not in the same folder as .tfignore.   
packages

# Exclude package target files which may be required for MSBuild, again prefixing the folder name as needed.
!packages/*.targets

# Omit temporary files
project.lock.json
project.assets.json
*.nuget.props
```